# Edit parameters in Settings file

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, app-config, application-settings

I have DataClasses.dbml file in my C# winforms project. This automatically adds a setting of type ConnectionString to Settings file of the project. The connection string throughout the project is accessed using this setting.

Now when I work on my PC, it connects to the database and works fine. But how to set a new connection string depending on client's host and instance names in the settings file permanently and for once (during setup).

I tried doing:

```
Settings.Default.ConnectionString = "SqlConnectionString";
Settings.Default.Save();
```

But it gives a compile-time error that its Read-Only.

My only aim is to set the connectionstrings according the clients setting. I dont want to make it hard coded.

Comment: How do you make setup? Do you use setup package, copy manually, etc?

Comment: @archil: I make setup using Setup and Deployment Project

Answer (score 1):

Add a `partial` class definition like the following

```
public partial class DataClasses
{       
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        Connection.ConnectionString = SQLHelpers.GetConnectionStr();
    }
}
```

where `SQLHelpers.GetConnectionStr` should lookup the settings from the users App.Config file.

Remember to put this in a separate file to your auto-generated dbml file.